# Complex variable, multiplication of numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, connectedness

**Question:**
Let a and b be complex numbers with $a \neq 0.$
Describe the set of points $az + b $ as $z$ varies over the first quadrant, $\{z = x+iy: x>0 \,and \,y>0\}$

**Solution:**
Let $a = |a|e^{i\theta_0}.$ Then $\{az+b: z \,\, in \,\,1st \, \,quadrant\} = \{b+se^{i\varphi}: 0<s<\infty, \,\theta_0 < \varphi < \theta_0 + \pi/2 \}$

**My questions:**
1) Does s = |a| ?
2) How did they obtain $\theta_0 < \varphi < \theta_0 + \pi/2 $ ? Are we rotating z by the argument of a ?
3) How would we express this in exponential form?
4) How do we know that this set of points does not include the boundary and thus it is open?
5) How is it connected?

Thank you very much!! Self-studying is sometimes frustrating but also fun. :p

Comment: Next time, consider showing some of your own work first.

Answer (score 0):

As the solution says, let $a=|a|e^{i\theta_0}$, for some $\theta_0\in[0,2\pi)$. The first quadrant $A_1:=\{z=x+iy:x>0\,\wedge\,y>0\}$ can be described equivalently as $A_1=\{re^{i\phi}\in\mathbb{C}:r\in\mathbb{R}_{>0},\wedge\,\phi\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})\}$. Then
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\{az+b:z\in A_1\}&=\{b+|a|re^{i\theta_0}e^{i\phi}:r\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\,\wedge\,\phi\in(0,\tfrac{\pi}{2})\} \\
&=\{b+se^{i(\theta_0+\phi)}:s\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\,\wedge\,\phi\in(0,\tfrac{\pi}{2})\} \\
&=\{b+se^{i\phi}:s\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\,\wedge\,\phi\in(\theta_0,\theta_0+\tfrac{\pi}{2})\} \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
since if $r$ ranges over $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, then $s=|a|r$ ranges over $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, and if $\phi\in(0,\tfrac{\pi}{2})$, then $\theta_0+\phi\in(\theta_0,\theta_0+\tfrac{\pi}{2})$. So:

No, $|a|\neq s$, as I described above.

Hopefully the $\theta_0<\phi<\theta_0+\tfrac{\pi}{2}$ is clear now. This certainly comes down to rotating the first quadrant by the argument of $a$, and also applying the transformation $z\to|a|z$ to it, but it is invariant under the last transformation.

If you really want to write this in exponential form (I don't know why it helps), you can simply say that the set is equal to $\{|b|e^{\arg(b)}+se^{i\phi}:s\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\,\wedge\,\phi\in(\theta_0,\theta_0+\tfrac{\pi}{2})\}$.

This set is clearly open since you have open conditions (i.e. inequalities) on the describing parameters $s$ and $\phi$. Also, the first quadrant is open and you have only rotated it and translated it by $b$, both of which are homeomorphisms and thus sends opens to opens. The boundary points are the points with $s=0$ or $\theta\in\{\theta_0,\theta_0+\tfrac{\pi}{2})$, which do not occur.

Again, since the first quadrant is trivially connected, the new set is too, since the transformations applied to it are continuous.